# Post data to mysql DB

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql

I'am trying to send data from android as JSON to PHP in order to parse it and save in MySQL DB

this is the part of the PHP CODE

```
$JsonString = $_POST["DATA"];
$JsonData = json_decode($JsonString, TRUE);

$Add_First_Only = 0;
foreach ($JsonData['items'] as $item)
{
    $Order_ID = $item['Order_ID'];
    $Order_Row_Number = $item['Order_Row_Number'];
    $Order_Item_ID = $item['Order_Item_ID'];
    $Order_Course_ID = $item['Order_Course_ID'];
    $Order_Seat_No = $item['Order_Seat_No'];
    $Order_Row_Value_wo_Options = $item['Order_Row_Value_wo_Options'];
    $Order_Row_Value_with_options = $item['Order_Row_Value_with_options'];

if ($Add_First_Only == 0)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con,
    "INSERT INTO order_items (Order_ID,Order_Row_Number,Order_Item_ID,Order_Course_ID,Order_Seat_No,Order_Row_Value_wo_Options, Order_Row_Value_with_options) 
    VALUES 
    (['$Order_ID'],['$Order_Row_Number'],['$Order_Item_ID'],['$Order_Course_ID'],
        ['$Order_Seat_No'],['$Order_Row_Value_wo_Options'],['$Order_Row_Value_with_options'])"
    );
    $Add_First_Only = 1;
}
}
```

and this is the error I get on the Eclipse LogCAT

> 12-16 02:00:01.800: V/TAG(1841): Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['26'],['1'],['1'],['1'],['1'],['0'],['1'])' at line 4

As you can see from the error it self that I have values for the variables so non of them is a null value

The Question is what should I change or add to my sql syntax to fix this error ?

Comment: Have you tried without the brackets `'$Order_ID',` instead of `['$Order_ID'],` etc. in `VALUES` ?

Comment: Please, learn to use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY). Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: That was it thanks a lot, If you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it for you, THNX @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets around `['$Order_ID']` and the others

Use `'$Order_ID'` instead of `['$Order_ID']` etc. for your `VALUES`

```
if ($Add_First_Only == 0)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con,
    "INSERT INTO order_items (Order_ID,Order_Row_Number,Order_Item_ID,Order_Course_ID,Order_Seat_No,Order_Row_Value_wo_Options, Order_Row_Value_with_options) 
    VALUES 
    ('$Order_ID','$Order_Row_Number','$Order_Item_ID','$Order_Course_ID',
        '$Order_Seat_No','$Order_Row_Value_wo_Options','$Order_Row_Value_with_options')"
    );
    $Add_First_Only = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't wrap the parameters in the SQL statemenst with square brackets (example: `['$Order_ID']`).

I often find it helpful to `echo` or `error_log` the SQL statement that is created and try running it in a SQL tool. This should give you better error messages, and reveal syntax errors (if the tool has syntax highlighting).

Also, look at what php.net has to say about [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). SQL-statements of this type are vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks which are one of the most common ways to attack systems.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Single quotes '' around the data you want to INSERT into DB you tell PHP that this data is string type and your database probably expects INTEGER data.